# Jquery file uploader and navigator

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a jQuery plug in that will allow me to upload files and/or navigate to files on the file system.

It would be used to allow a visitor to add multiple images to a news article.

I am using ASP.NET MVC so it would have to be compatible with that.

Edit: Something like this would work great - [KFM Demo](http://kfm.verens.com/demo/1.3.1/?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

A quick search at jQuery returns several results that you could use:

[jQuery Search: file upload](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/file+upload)

All of these are going to add the ability to select files and upload them to the server. The rub here is that **jQuery is a javascript library and only runs on the client side**. You're going to need to write server side code in your .NET MVC application to process the file uploads as you get them from the client.

Comment: I understand that I would need to process it server side as well but I am looking for a file manager to pass the files on to the server side. Kinda of like most WYSIWYG editors have an image browser tool.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no plugin ready to do all that you want, but you could mix a JavaScript/Flash file uploading library (I like [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)) and jQuery UI to make a simple photo manager.

Check this [jQuery UI droppable demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/photo-manager.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [JsonResult Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) works like a charm.

From the docs:

> Represents a class that is used to send JSON-formatted content to the response.

### Syntax

```
public class JsonResult : ActionResult
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) in the past, as long as you're not doing anything crazy with authentication (windows) this works really well.  Allows multiple uploads and if your used to working with ajax in jQuery and MVC, it is fairly easy to setup and get working.